# Etymology of "heulandite"?

Tags: etymology

Came across the word "heulandite", thought it was weird so I looked it up in the dictionary and found that it means: "a group of minerals of the zeolite family consisting of a hydrous aluminum silicate of sodium and calcium." I looked up "-ite" on [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ite&allowed_in_frame=0) so I suspect the suffix comes from Greek meaning: "connected with or belonging to." Where does the "heuland" part come from? Is it related to "andesite" or maybe something else?

Comment: [named after H. Heuland, 19th-century English mineral collector](http://www.memidex.com/heulandite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED gives it as named after a mineralogist (presumably the chap who first identified it):

> Pronunciation:  /ˈhjuːləndaɪt/
>   Etymology:  Named 1822 after H. *Heuland,* an English mineralogist: see **-ite** *suffix*<sup>1</sup>.
>   *Mineral.*
>
> A mineral of the Zeolite group; a hydrated silicate of aluminium and calcium, found in crystals of various colours with pearly lustre.

In that regard, the name is related to Andesite in as much as it's named after a particular property of the mineral: in this case, who identified it; in the case of Andesite, where it is found.